# In Middleman, redirects to a temporary home page in my config.rb not working

Tags: redirect, middleman

Originally in my config.rb I had the following:

```
activate :i18n, mount_at_root: false, langs: ['en-us', 'es-mx']
activate :directory_indexes

redirect 'index.html', to: 'en-us'
```

This works great for redirecting `localhost:4567/` to `localhost:4567/en-us`. However, I would actually like to redirect `localhost:4567/` and `localhost:4567/en-us` to `localhost:4567/en-us/temporary-home-page`.

Changing my previous redirect in config.rb works fine:

```
redirect 'index.html', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
```

When I try adding the redirect for `localhost:4567/en-us`, it doesn't work:

```
redirect 'en-us/index.html', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
```

I still end up on `localhost:4567/en-us`. I also tried each of the following combinations with the same result:

```
redirect 'en-us', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
redirect 'en-us/', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
redirect 'en-us/index.html', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
redirect '/en-us', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
redirect '/en-us/', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
redirect '/en-us/index.html', to: "en-us/temporary-home-page"
```

On some it would output this in the browser:

```
            <html>
              <head>
                <link rel="canonical" href="en-us/temporary-home-page" />
                <meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=en-us/temporary-home-page" />
                <meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />
                <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
              </head>
              <body>
              </body>
            </html>
```

What am I missing? How can I get the `/`, `/en-us`, and `/en-us/` URLs to redirect to `/en-us/temporary-home-page`?

Comment: were you missing the file extension for the page you were trying to redirect to?

Comment: Don't add a beginning slash in the first string. Also add the file extension to the redirect path.